# Custom Linear Component Constructor not inflating XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have made a custom Number Picker extending a Linear Layout, i have issue with the constructors, for some reason the activity is not inflating the XML when i pass an enum to the constructor. Here is the code.

```
 private TumblerSettings.TumblerTypes tumblerTypes;

public Tumbler(Context context, TumblerListener tumblerCallBack, TumblerSettings.TumblerTypes
        tumblerTypes)
{
    super(context);
    this.mTumblerCallBack = tumblerCallBack;
    this.tumblerTypes = tumblerTypes;
    Log.i("sss", "Tumbler1: " + String.valueOf(tumblerTypes));
    updateValue();
    initControl(context);
    //setCustomObjectListener(mTumblerCallBack);
}

public Tumbler(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, TumblerSettings.TumblerTypes
        tumblerTypes)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    this.tumblerTypes = tumblerTypes;
    Log.i("sss", "Tumbler2: "  + String.valueOf(tumblerTypes));
    updateValue();
    initControl(context);
}

public Tumbler(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle, TumblerSettings.TumblerTypes
        tumblerTypes)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.tumblerTypes = tumblerTypes;
    Log.i("sss", "Tumbler3: "  + String.valueOf(tumblerTypes));
    updateValue();
    initControl(context);

}
```

And im calling it with this code

```
mTumbler = new Tumbler(MainActivity.this, new Tumbler.TumblerListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void tumblerValue(final String value)
        {
            valueTextView.setText("value :" + value);
        }
    }, TumblerSettings.TumblerTypes.BRIGHTNESS);
```

The error im getting is

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wheelsample/com.example.wheelsample.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.example.wheelsample.tumblers.Tumbler
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)

Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated. Thank you

XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.wheelsample.DualNumberPicker">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@drawable/assets_tmb_wide"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.example.wheelsample.TumblerNumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/bpp"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is some confusion in the way you are trying to create your view. You have two options for creating a view.

### XML inflation:

You declare your view in your XML file and, after calling `setContentView` from your `Activity`, you can use `findViewById()` to get an instance to it.

#### Example

Let's say your custom view is called `Tumbler` and your package name is `com.example` and you have it declared like this in your XML file:

```
<com.example.Tumbler
  android:id="@+id/my_tumbler"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then you'll be able to get an instance to it by calling:

`Tumbler tumbler = (Tumbler) findViewById(R.id.my_tumbler);`

#### Programmatic instantiation

If you opt for not using XML at all, you can create your own view instance:

`Tumbler tumbler = new Tumbler(this);`

Then you'll have to add it to a parent view in your view hierarchy by calling `addView()`. But this is not really what you want, so I suggest you take the first approach.

This code:

```
mTumbler = new Tumbler(MainActivity.this, new Tumbler.TumblerListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void tumblerValue(final String value)
        {
            valueTextView.setText("value :" + value);
        }
    }, TumblerSettings.TumblerTypes.BRIGHTNESS);
```

Can be replaced by:

`mTumbler = (Tumbler) findViewById(R.id.your_tumbler_id_just_like_in_xml_file);`

And then you call a setter method to set your enum value:

`mTumbler.setTumblerType(TumblerSettings.TumblerTypes.BRIGHTNESS)`

The whole thing is that the system calls `View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` constructor when it inflates an XML file. You can't just add custom arguments to your constructors, unless if you are going to create your instances dynamically in Java. Use a setter method instead.

For a nice explanation on how view constructors work, check this page:

http://blog.danlew.net/2016/07/19/a-deep-dive-into-android-view-constructors/

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, i have removed the arguments from the constructor and added a setter method, im still getting the same error android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have accepted it.. there is a small issue with the setter it is called after the view is created, in the main activity i require it to be called first then the view to be set. il play around around.. thank you